# Tfs 2012 express RC trial ended first day

Tags: tfs

I download and Installed VSTFS 2012 Express RC version and added few sample project collection in TFSAdmin console, while I am trying to access the project via web access it showing following message.

```
 TF246019: The Team Foundation Server trial period has expired, or the license is not valid. You must update your license in order to continue to use Team Foundation Server.
```

In RC version trial period seems to be 90 days, but expired after the installation. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I didn't try but usually when you have issues like that it's become of the system date&time.

Comment: System date and time are synchronised

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Team Foundation server app pool was running 32-bit mode

You can set the 32-bit application setting in IIS 7 Manager by opening the ‘Advanced Settings’ for the app pool and change Change the Enable 32-bit Applications to False.

[image: Advanced settings]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there were 58 days left on my trial - as per Sebastiaan's case, the "trial period has expired" message was a complete red herring.

The problem was fixed by a stop/start of the Microsoft Team Foundation Server Application Pool.

[image: Application Pools]